# How to use SixLabors.ImageSharp in a Azurefunction project

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, .net-6.0, imagesharp

I need to use ImageSharp to handle images on my Azure function. But even after adding the reference, I still can't reference it from the c# code. In other solutions related to the library, they mention to add configuration in the startup.cs of an API, which is not my case.

This is my .csproj

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ...
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="3.0.1" />
    ...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And in the c# code, this gets "The type or namespace name 'SixLabors.ImageSharp' could not be found"

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats;
```

Comment: Might be mistaken but judging from the packages nuGet-page, ImageSharp does not support your TargetFramework. see: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SixLabors.ImageSharp/#supportedframeworks-body-tab

Comment: Downgrading the version of `SixLabors.ImageSharp` to `2.1.4` allows you to add the mentioned namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Sancho Panza for the comment.

As mentioned by Sancho Panza, the latest version `3.0.1`of
`SixLabors.ImageSharp` is only compatible with .NET 6.0 and above.

- The versions compatible with `.NET Core 3.1` are shown below.

[image]

[image]

If you want to continue with the former version of `.NET 3.1`, then downgrade the `SixLabors.ImageSharp` version to `2.1.4`.

Now Iam able to add the namespaces for the below without any issues with the older versions.

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="2.1.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]